# How can I solve this error for android application

Tags: android

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output.   CAS     Unknown Android Packaging Problem

This is from Eclipse

Comment: Try to delete the error from your error list, clean the project and rebuild it.